# UIPickerView not Showing Data from array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a simple picker view. this is what I've got so far but no data is shown. Most help I've found says to put the pickerview code under `viewDidLoad` but this is not on my main `ViewController`, so I'm not sure if that is the problem.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AddViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let formulaNumbers = ["Formula1", "Formula2", "Formula3", "Formula4", "Formula5", "Formula6"]
    let numberOfBatches = [1...100]

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerUI: UIPickerView!

    @IBAction func dissmissButton(_ sender:Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return formulaNumbers.count
        }
        return numberOfBatches.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return formulaNumbers[row]
        }
        return "\(numberOfBatches[row])"
    }
}
```

What is the issue and what should I do? and thank you, in advance.

Comment: Please assign delegate and datasource to self in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to confirm the `delegate` and `dataSource` to your `AddViewController` for `pickerUI`

so in `viewDidLoad` method add

```
pickerUI.dataSource = self
pickerUI.delegate = self
```

And your method will look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    pickerUI.dataSource = self
    pickerUI.delegate = self
}
```